# Servicemix Spring 4 wiring issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, osgi, apache-servicemix

**Edit:**
To better/shorter folmulate my main question;
Is it possible to get an OSGI application running using spring-osgi (1.2.1) and Spring 4 at the same time? And if so, *how*?

**Original:**

I am trying to make servicemix 6.1.3 work with Spring 4. 
I know support has been officially dropped as of Spring version 3 but I need spring 4 for security reasons and frankly keeping our application up to date with newer functionality.
So I imported the required [servicemix spring V4 bundles](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context).

The issue here is that our application also uses the spring-osgi functionality (so not the abovementioned osgi-ified bundles by servicemix but the actual spring-osgi bundles which have V 1.2.1 as seen below)

The error:

```
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
        Unable to execute command on bundle 352: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve bundle revision my.app.service [352.7] because it is exposed to package 'org.springframework.context.support' from bundle revisions org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-
context [240.0] and org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context [105.0] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  my.app.service [352.7]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.context.support)(version>=4.2.0)(version<=4.4.0))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.context.support
  org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context [240.0]

Chain 2:
  my.app.service [352.7]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support)(version>=1.2.1))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.osgi.web.context.support; uses:=org.springframework.osgi.context.support
  org.springframework.osgi.web [252.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.osgi.context.support)(version>=1.2.1)(version<=1.2.1))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.osgi.context.support; uses:=org.springframework.context.support
  org.springframework.osgi.core [109.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.context.support)(version>=2.5.6)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.context.support
  org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context [105.0]
```

Now as you can see the issue is that I have spring-context twice running in servicemix. Once from the default installation [105] (I expect on the background a lot of servicemix's bundles (camel, activeMQ, etc) are using Spring 3, hence I dont want to remove them in fear of other issues; but if you know better, please enlighten me) and a Spring V4 bundle [240].

Our usage of spring-osgi requires us to use its bundles which are hardcoded to use "org.springframework.context.support version>=2.5.6 !version>=4.0.0".

Now my question;
- Is there a way around this? To force org.springframework.osgi.core to use the spring-context V4 bundle? Or is it just impossible to use Spring 4 at the same time as Spring 3's OSGI bundles?

**Additional info:**

I used the following in my pom's maven-bundle-plugin import-Package tag to enforce usage of Spring 4: (spring.version=[4.2,4.4])

```
org.springframework.context.support;version="${spring.version}",
```

And in the parent pom has the following in the dependency-management section.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Edit 2:**

Maybe I can manually bypass the `org.springframework.context.support (version>=2.5.6)(!(version>=4.0.0))` requirement by downloading the spring osgi 1.2.x branch [from github](https://github.com/kurtharriger/spring-osgi/blob/spring-osgi-1.2/pom.xml), change the  in the pom and recompile.
Still obviously this isnt a good solution at all sice im hacking myself through to unsupported versions, so please advise.

Comment: First of all spring-osgi is EOL now for quite some time. So might want to check how the guys at the apache karaf project handle the spring stuff.

Comment: Small update; I am now integrating the project which continued on Spring DM (spring-osgi) which is Gemini Blueprint. Will update with my findings with an answer to this post once I am done.